# Android: JSONArray into ExpandableList issue

Tags: android, arrays, json, expandablelistview

I want to make an expandable list with a JSONArray.
The app works but not perfectly. I guess i have trouble with the for() statment.
Here is the code:

```
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
listDataChild = new HashMap<>();
String json_string;

try {
    json_string = json;

    jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
        object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++) {
            //Check with Log.e
            Log.e(TAG, "Key = " + object.names().getString(i) + " value = " + object.get(object.names().getString(i)));
            /*** Working with ExpandableList ***/
            listDataHeader.add(object.names().getString(i));
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add((object.get(object.names().getString(i))).toString());
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), list);
        }

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty JSON");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And there is the JSON String:

```
{
"server_response": [{
    "Medii Vizuale De Programare": "10",
    "Retele De Calculatoare": "8",
    "Tehnici Avansate De Programare": "9",
    "Tehnologii Web": "9",
    "Baza De Date": "9",
    "Programare Functionala": ""
}, {
    "Medii Vizuale De Programare": "8",
    "Retele De Calculatoare": "5",
    "Tehnici Avansate De Programare": "6",
    "Tehnologii Web": "7",
    "Baza De Date": "10",
    "Programare Functionala": "8"
}]}
```

So, the problem is when i want to see the values then just the first object are showed, the second not.
Any idea?

Comment: what is your header and content in this response!!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looping on a JsonObject, you have to loop on the JsonArray

```
if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.e(TAG, "Key = " + object.names().getString(i) + " value = " + object.get(object.names().getString(i)));
       /*** Working with ExpandableList ***/
       listDataHeader.add(object.names().getString(i));
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add((object.get(object.names().getString(i))).toString());
       listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), list);
    }
    :
    :
}//if array >0
```

Comment: it does't work. now only this two elements are visible: Medii Vizuale De Programare": "10",
    "Retele De Calculatoare": "5"

Comment: @LászlóCsiki it's obvious that you don't understand JSON structure, JsonArray, JsonObject. this is correct output as the json you are showing is an array of 2 objects, if you want to read each property in each object, this is another story.

Comment: Yes, it's obvius, but i want to understand it. Can you help me?

Comment: @LászlóCsiki you have to get each property by it's name `object.get("property_name")` or if `object.names()` returns some kind of array or list, then you need another `for loop` inside the first one to iterate over each object properties and get them

Comment: Thanks! I will try it :) @Yazan